# Why would an Azure SQL query use 29 seconds of CPU sometimes, 0.1 ms other times on an idle 10 core pool?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

Using an Azure SQL elastic pool with 10 cores when it is completely idle (over a weekend), query store shows an SP/query using 29 seconds of CPU and causing a high average CPU usage alert to trigger at 80%.

I recreated the situation when the pool was also idle the following Monday early morning, and fired the SP/Query with the same parameter values and watched for the results in sys.dm_exec_query_stats.
CPU was about 0.1 ms.  Query store showed it used the same QueryId, same PlanId, same distribution of load evenly spread throughout the plan.  Also, the plan did not go parallel.

Because it was over a weekend, the volume of data in the tables had not changed in any measurable way.  I also checked that the data being returned by the SP existed months before this incident so it is not a case of the results changing in between times.

I'm much more of a developer than a DBA, so can anyone me where else to look to find out why, and how, a query could perform so drastically different under the apparent same environment?  Is this a phenomenon that has something to do with the serverless environment of Azure SQL specifically?

Some more stats requested in comments:

- compile time for both query runs was 77ms and 47ms CPU.
- plan was retrieved from cache in both instances.
- wait time doesn't seem to be available for the short run time.
- wait time was "CPU" 6303ms for the long run time.

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: How long does the execution plan take to compile?

Comment: Hi @MartinSmith both sessions took 77 ms to compile and were retrieved from cache.

Comment: Have you managed to reproduce the execution that takes 29 seconds of CPU time and captured the actual execution plan for that? If not what does this 77ms relate to? I think trying to repro it and getting the actual execution plan will be the best approach anyway as the issue is presumably one or other of (1) Inherently long CPU time to compile the plan (2) CPU time spent on updating stats (3) Operator(s) in the execution plan using a lot of CPU - and the actual execution plan will show all of that information

Comment: Sadly no.  And I think my earlier attempt did use a different plan than I thought, so not a fair comparison.  Seems I do have a CPU wait issue with this particular plan though.

Comment: Maintenance schedule is set to run over weekends, that would slow down cpu.

Answer (score 2):

This is a standard SQL Server pattern. The first time you run a query it has to do a lot of physical IO, memory allocation raises and it's slow. You may take a look at queries performing slow and they may be showing the PAGEIOLATCH_SH and MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT waits and that corresponds to pages being pulled from disk to the buffer. The second time you run the query the data is in buffers and it's fast.

After a period of inactivity memory allocation drops. Azure SQL Database shrinks memory allocation after the database has not been used for some time or the database tier has been scaled up or down. You will see this happening on Azure SQL Database but not on SQL Server instances (IaaS). If you set a database as Serverless you will see memory is reclaimed even more frequently as you can read in the Azure SQL Serverless documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview?view=azuresql&tabs=general-purpose#memory-management), and that has a greater impact in performance.

Another possible reason is queries are waiting for a synchronous statistics update to complete before the compilation and then execution can resume. Please try to enable Async update statistics as explained [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-database-support-blog/improving-performance-with-auto-update-statistics-async/ba-p/3579907?wt.mc_id=DP-MVP-4015656). Regularly updating statistics removing index fragmentation can improve the performance also, so no need to update stats prior to execute queries because they are updated by a maintenance job regularly.

Comment: If it is waiting it isn't using CPU

Comment: Examine the waits as explained here https://sqlcoffee.com/Azure_0017.htm. You will probable see IO or memory allocation related waits.

Comment: I'm not the OP - but if it is waiting on IO related waits that would explain a higher duration but not a higher CPU time. CPU time indicates it is busy doing some activity rather than waiting

Comment: If you are waiting for the stats to be refreshed before running the query you will see spike on CPU while stats are being updated. See the last paragraph of my answer

Comment: yeah could be that, or just a query that takes a long time to compile in general even without stats refresh

Comment: Async Update Stats can really reduce that kind of issues of queries having poor performance on first execution (afer a good period of time - hours/minutes), especially when big tables are involved on those queries.

Comment: Thanks @AlbertoMorillo!  It seems I have a CPU Wait issue going on so I'll look into statistics a little closer and get those updating more often.

Comment: Simon before you go deeper, please update stats and defrag indexes using Ola Hallengreen scripts or your own scripts, if the situation continues then examine the query plan.

Comment: Thanks Alberto.  Definitely setting up Ola Hallengreen's script as a nightly job - seems to help quite a lot.  Now have to work on some SPs that just have too many plans to choose from!

Comment: That's great news. I am very happy for you. That means the update of stats was delaying query execution. Perfect

Answer (score 0):

I have had a near identical problem and am similarly totally stuck on a solution. Running the query once takes 30s running it again it completes in under 1s. It also doesnt seem to matter if it's the exact same query. Same code, different parameter value and subsequent executions as as fast as expected. I originally thought it was an issue with the serverless wake time but auto-pause is disabled. It seems to be tied to even minor periods of inactivity (10 mins or so). I do have my serverless db set with 0.5 min vCores but it scales to 6 vCores. I'm assuming this play some sort of role in creating the issue. According to GPT, it can take a little time to scale resources appropriately.

UPDATE: After extensive research and chatting with GPT the issue seems to be caused by Azure releasing data out of memory. I noticed spikes in my IO after small periods of inactivity (~10 mins). If you compare the XML of the execution plans for both queries, you'll noticed that the long running one needs to read the table into memory (hence the IO spike). Once the data is in memory it runs much faster. There appear to be two ways to solve this, by regularly pinging the table to keep the data in memory (I'm going to set this up). OR if you're using a higher service tier, you could use a memory optimized table to keep the data in memory but that is not available on my tier.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't work in Azure SQL anymore, or I would try this out.  It sure seems to fit the symptoms very well!  Thanks for the input @Logan!  ... Yet another reason **not** to use Azure SQL.